# What is the correct import path for memcache on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

All examples for importing memcache (that I have seen) show it as:

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
```

However, with 1.9.15 App Engine lib I just downloaded, I noticed that there is a class called `Client`, and the `get` method is a method of that class. This is why PyDev was throwing import errors for the `get`, `set`, `incr` functions. It worked fine in production though. When I changed the function to memcache.Client.get because that is what it looked like in the local library code, production started throwing errors.

What is the right import path for memcache, one that will work in both prod and not throw an error in dev_appserver?

Comment: does it actually throw an error or is it just the IDE complaining?

Comment: You're right, only the IDE shows the error. But where is that import coming from?

Comment: You will have a directory like 'google_appengine_1.9.15/google/appengi
ne/api/' in your SDK - it lives in there